# client/server communication

Tags: android, client-server

I am new to android and I need to develop an application which stores the location information in server. And now another application should receive it from the server and display it in textview. Is there any way to do it. please help.

Comment: One way to do this is, make webservice for giving response in xml at server side and use xml parsing to read that xml in android application.

Comment: @Dhrupal are you saying about Json ?

Comment: Badly phrased question, of course there's a way to do it, there are plenty of apps that do it. I guess what he meant was more in the direction of code examples...

Comment: Yes. Thant is also fine for client server communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate to other devices/servers you need some protocol. You can use your own socket, or use Http Protocol.
By Using HttpProtocol you can invoke a url, post some data to url, get some data from the url.
Now, If you have decided to go to Http Connection, you would need some webservices, by which you can send and receive data from url, there are various types of webservices, in which, two are mostly used.
1. Rest Services
2. Soap Webservices

and you can send and receive data, either in xml or json, as both are very standardized and easy to use.

Comment: Actually you can use HTTP connection without using XML-based web-services. I managed to do it with simple `POST HTTP request`  ;)

Comment: yes, you can, I suggested xml cause its widely used, and you can find its parser very easily.

Comment: Easier than one line of code (in PHP and JSP for example) ? :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with web service. you have to get your gps location from your application and send it to server through web service. In server side you have to store it in DB. After that an another application that checks whether a new data is available in DB. If new data is available it get the data through web service and display it in the Text view.

Answer (score 1):

well all you need to understand is the client / server architecture first and undestand the logic of consuming and accessing web services.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr) is the complete guide for this.

Hope this helps.